# Is it possible to obtain ffmpeg.exe for Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS?

Tags: ffmpeg

Python web IDE [replit.com](https://replit.com) is running on Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS OS. I need to be able to use `ffmpeg.exe`, to run [a line](https://holypython.com/how-to-save-matplotlib-animations-the-ultimate-guide/) like

```
mpl.rcParams['animation.ffmpeg_path'] = r'C:\\Users\\xx\\Desktop\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe'
```

Is it possible? Which executable should I use? The list of downloadable Ubuntu FFmpeg files is [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ffmpeg/7:5.1.1-1ubuntu1), presumably.

`apt install ffmpeg` fails:

```
apt install ffmpeg
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?
```

`lsb_release -a` output:

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

Comment: If you need an application to do your work, submit a Change Request through your Change Board to ask for the necessary application (`ffmpeg`) to be installed

Comment: It says right there in the error message that you need to be root to install packages with `apt`.

Comment: @NasirRiley, yes, I thought that perhaps there could be another way...

Comment: If you want to use `apt` to install ffmpeg, then there is not. You need to have sudoer rights. The only that you have without them is to compile ffmpeg from source.

Answer (score 3):

You can always install `ffmpeg` with:

```
sudo apt install ffmpeg
```

Then edit the script and use ffmpeg instead of

```
C:\\Users\\xx\\Desktop\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe
```

which is a MS-Windows executable.

Assuming proper `PATH` and such:

```
mpl.rcParams['animation.ffmpeg_path'] = r'ffmpeg'
```

(and you probably don't need the `r` prefix).

Although it is possible to run many `.exe` files with Wine, I would not recommend it in this situation.

Comment: apt install ffmpeg fails - I have added the error messages to the text of my question.

Comment: @YuliaV Ha, sorry, you need to use `sudo` so you are root when installing.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a programmer, just a Linux user.

Linux does not use `.exe` files, but they do have programs you can run.

To install the package, run this command:

```
apt install ffmpeg
```

I am not sure if [replit.com](https://replit.com) will notice the installed `ffmpeg` binary, but you should be able to use the full path of `ffmpeg` to make it work.

Comment: apt install ffmpeg fails - I have added the error messages to the text of my question